# Adding JSON elements to two dimensional array

Tags: javascript, jquery

Good Day,

I have this JSON object that i want to push and change the two values in to another array

```
var line4 = [
{"viewed":2, "sumDate":1377129600000, "redeemed" : 8}, 
{"viewed":12, "sumDate":1377129600000, "redeemed" : 3}, 
{"viewed":18, "sumDate":1377129600000, "redeemed" : 13} 
];
```

i want the new line4 to be like this format

```
newline4 = [["2008-06-30", 2], ["2008-7-14", 12, ["2008-7-28", 18]]
```

i cant seem to format it correctly to my array

```
$(line4).each(function (index, value) {
    console.log("value: " + value);
    $(value).map(function(){         
        d = new Date(parseInt(this.sumDate));
        this.sumDate = (1 + d.getMonth()) + '/'+ d.getDate() + '/'  + d.getFullYear().toString().slice(-2);
        console.log("sumdate : " +this.sumDate);
        console.log("viewed : " +this.viewed);

        newline4.push([this.sumDate, this.viewed]);    
    });

});
```

but im getting

```
newline4 : 8/21/13,2,8/21/13,12,8/21/13,18
```

Comment: WHat is `$(line4)` supposed to be? Assuming you're using jQuery, the argument to `$()` should be either a DOM element or a selector, I've never heard of using an array as the argument.

Comment: its my JSON object that i want to iterate with into a new array of object [[],[]]

Comment: It should just be `line4.each(...)`, not `$(line4).each()`. But apparently jQuery is permissive, and `$(line4)` is the same as `line4`.

Comment: thanks for the reply, this question was already answered on this link http://jsfiddle.net/L5vf9/

Comment: If you want `-` between the parts of the date, why are you putting `/` between them in the line `this.sumDate = `?

Comment: Other than the `-` vs `/` issue, your code works as desired for me.

Answer (score 0):

You're using the wrong form of each and map. jQuery(selector/element/jQuery).each is meant for iterating over DOM elements. You want to be using:

```
$.each(line4, function(index, value){
```

Also, $.map only works on Arrays. Looking at what you're trying to do, however, I don't think you need map at all. You're already accessing each object with .each() - you can't map an object and you certainly can't access properties of the object within the map. You should just be able to remove the map portion.

```
var newline4 = [];
$.each(line4, function(index, value){
    // use "var" so as not to make this a global variable
    var d = new Date(parseInt(value.sumDate));
    var sumDate = (1 + d.getMonth()) + '/'+ d.getDate() + '/'  + d.getFullYear().toString().slice(-2);
    newline4.push([sumDate, value.viewed]);
});
```

Comment: Thanks tandrewnichols, but i have already solved it using the code below

`test`